# visa application 4uk decision

Tags: visas

could you kindly tell me what it does mean

```
tma__application_decision_made_description %s

tma__application_decision_made

tma__application_decision_made_description %s

tma__avs_selected (tick)
tma__avs_paid (tick)
tma__application_submitted (tick)
tma__application_transferred_to_dmc (tick)
tma__application_received_by_dmc (tick)
tma__application_decision_made (tick)
tma__passback_from_consulate_courier ( not tick yet)
tma__passport_send_to_applicant(not tick yet)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about travel. It might (with clarification necessary) belong to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: What is the context of these list items? Where do you see them?

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with the site you are visiting. The text you see are actually labels (placeholders) which should be populated with the correct terms based on the language selected by the system.

Normally, you don't see these but rather the result once this template has been processed by the system.

Sometimes, due to overload or other system issues - these templates are rendered "as is"; which is what you are seeing.

Note that this has no impact on the status of your visa application.

The best you can do is reload the page or try at a different time.